# How to perform input checks in TextInputDialog in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have the code below. It describes a simple *TextInputDialog* (which contains a text field and OK button).
How can I perform input checks? (e.g verify that the input is numeric/not-empty and so and so).
In the bottom line, **I want that the OK button will be disabled if the input is wrong, or if I press OK then nothing will happen if the input is wrong.**

```
TextInputDialog tid = new TextInputDialog("250");
tid.setTitle("Text Input Dialog");
tid.setHeaderText("Input check example");
tid.setContentText("Please enter a number below 100:");
Optional<String> result = tid.showAndWait();
result.ifPresent(name -> System.out.println("Your name: " + name));
```

In the "ifPresent" section, I can check the input but it will be after the dialog will be closed.
How can I fix it?

[image: Here is the dialog]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `getEditor()` on the `TextInputDialog` to get the underlying `TextField` and `lookupButton(ButtonType)` on the `DialogPane` of the dialog to get the OK-`Button`. Then you can use a binding to implement your desired behavior:

```
Button okButton = (Button) tid.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
TextField inputField = tid.getEditor();
BooleanBinding isInvalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> isInvalid(inputField.getText()), inputField.textProperty());
okButton.disableProperty().bind(isInvalid);
```

Now you can create a method `isInvalid()` that validates your input and either returns `true` (if the button should be disabled), or `false` (if it should be enabled).

Of course, you can turn this logic around and create a `isValid` method instead by using the `not()` method on the binding.

Comment: Using `not()` wouldn't be neccessary. You create a `BooleanBinding` anyway, so you can simply do the negation in the `Callable`: `BooleanBinding isInvalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !isValid(inputField.getText()), inputField.textProperty());`