# Why are the javafx Input checks not working in scala

Tags: scala, javafx

[How to perform input checks in TextInputDialog in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092074/how-to-perform-input-checks-in-textinputdialog-in-javafx)

The above link basically covers the answer to my question but it doesn't work for me in scala.  I have a TextField (eTextField) and I want to check that it contains either a R or D.  If it does than the button (ePR_ePD) should be enabled.  Here is the part of my code that should do it, but it doesn't enable the button:

```
      val isInvalid: BooleanBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() => !isValid(eTextField.getText, eTextField.textProperty))
      println(isInvalid)
      ePR_ePD.disableProperty().bind(isInvalid)

def isValid (eText: String, eTextProp: StringProperty): Boolean = {
    println(eText.contains("R")||eText.contains("D"))
    eText.contains("R")||eText.contains("D")
}
```

When the eTextField contains a R or D my output is:

```
BooleanBinding [invalid]
true
```

and when it does not contain either my output is:

```
BooleanBinding [invalid]
false
```

But in both cases the ePR_ePD button says disabled.  It appears it is something to do with the BooleanBinding, since it is always invalid.

Also not sure why isValid(eTextField.getText, eTextField.textProperty) needs to have the textProperty parameter, but that is what the answer in the link showed.  Also tried "var isInvalid..." but that didn't help.

Comment: I haven't used Scala in a long time, so can no longer answer your question.  Perhaps you might want to use a TextFormatter instead, though perhaps not as your requirements may differ.

Comment: I don’t use Scala either, but some of this just looks wrong. `isValid` should *not* have a `TextProperty` parameter, and it should be `Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () => !isValid(eTextField.getText), eTextField.textProperty )`. (The `TextProperty` is a parameter to `createBooleanBinding(…)`, not to `isValid(…)`). That’s how it is done in the answer you linked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works, after I fixed the problem that I forgot to enter the fx:id in SceneBuilder for the ePR_ePD button:

(In the initialize() method of the fxml controller:)

```
   val isInvalid: BooleanBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () => !(isValid(eTextField.getText)), eTextField.textProperty)
    ePR_ePD.disableProperty().bind(isInvalid)
  }
```

(Outside the initialize() method:)

```
      def isValid (eText: String): Boolean = {
        println(eText.contains("R")||eText.contains("D"))
        eText.contains("R")||eText.contains("D")
      }
```

The only odd thing is that it appears to call isValid twice when I use another method to automatically change the contents of the eTextField.  My output is false false when there is no R or D in the field and true true when either is present.

This also works, without an isValid method:

(In the initialize() method of the fxml controller:)

```
       val isInvalid: BooleanBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () => !(eTextField.getText.contains("R")||eTextField.getText.contains("D")), eTextField.textProperty
       )

ePR_ePD.disableProperty().bind(isInvalid)
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: It's not at all clear what this offers that the previously-provided answer by @Tim did not. It seems extremely rude to plagiarize an answer someone has spent the time to provide, and then accept your "own" answer.

Comment: James,  As I said above, "Thanks to everyone for your help!".  I'm kind of new to the the voting etc on StackOverFlow.  Your help was greatly appreciated.  I just thought I would provide exactly what worked for me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) and as noted in the comments, `createBooleanBinding` takes two arguments, the function and the observable.

The function just tests the property value so `isValid` does not need the second argument. (The clue is that the second argument is not actually used)

```
def isValid (eText: String): Boolean = 
    eText.contains("R")|| eText.contains("D")
```

The property itself is passed as a second parameter to `createBooleanBinding` rather than to `isValid`:

```
createBooleanBinding(() => !isValid(eTextField.getText), eTextField.textProperty)
```

Comment: "`createBooleanBinding` takes two arguments, the function and the observable". Technically it takes one or more arguments (else the OP's code would not compile): the function and zero or more observables.